# Wordpress: Connecting ftp with code snippet good idea or bad?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I am developing a database for a client via wordpress. I know that there are ways to use plugins such as Woody Code snippets or Insert PHP snippets. From my understanding, one can just paste in single pages of code. But how can one use FTPs such as Cpanel, or WP admin with something that only allows one page of code?

Would it be good practice to use a php code plugin to upload my database with code? Or is there some other alternative that enables better FTP and file sharing with databases?

Comment: Before you go too far down this path, are you **absolutely sure** you want to grant the ability to paste arbitrary PHP code into a template by your client? If I'm not understanding this correctly, can you elaborate further?

Comment: I want to upload a database onto his wordpress site. I created all the databases on php myadmin, coded it out and made it run successfully on localhost, and even purchased cpanel to help in my efforts. I am unsure how to run all of my code on specific pages.

Comment: Is there some other method to run ftp files on specific parts of wordpress sites?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean by "FTP files". Are you talking about PHP code that does something with FTP, perhaps using functions such as `ftp_connect`, or are you talking about something else? WordPress is generally extended through plugins although that can be done with the theme, too, and pages are controlled by templates. If you want to inject your stuff in the middle of other existing things, that is often done with shortcodes. So there's a lot of different things that can be done if you can clarify things further.

Comment: I made a complete CRUD application that allowed me to create, read, update, and delete records on the fly. All the records were stored in a database on my local machine. I want to be able to create a "Hello world" script onto a dummy page of the wordpress site. I just do not know how to post and run the code.

Comment: I had purchased Cpanel through godaddy which allowed me to be able to transfer files to a server. The entire CRUD application is on my server. I just don't know how to run all of my files onto one of the wordpress pages. For instance, I would like to add a text box on a page that has a button when clicked sends data to my database.

Comment: If you want WordPress to interact with your custom PHP system, your life will generally be easier if you treat it as a plugin. That doesn't mean you have to change a lot, necessarily, although in the long run it would be better. For instance, if your CRUD was at example.com/crud/admin.php it would now be at example.com/wp-content/plugins/crud/admin.php with zero changes required. To become a plugin, you just need a bit of special code in index.php which you can find online. From there, have that file register a couple of helper functions or shortcodes for WordPress to pick up.

Comment: But WordPress in no way messes with your PHP application, and PHP continues to work the way you expect (as long as your expectations are valid and sane, I guess). Your CRUD application could optionally register a REST API endpoint with WordPress, and the WordPress code calls the endpoint which is your unaltered code, potentially.